# CS193p Stanford API Error Assignment 4

Tags: objective-c, json, nsdictionary

i am following the iTunes U Course CS193p for iOS 7 and now i am working on the assignment no.4 and i have a problem when i try to log the dictionary propertyListResults

i think there is an error in the API!

it says in the console { code = 100 , message = @"Invalid API Key (Key has invalid format)" , stat = fail }

and this is the code of the method fetchPhotos

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self fetchPhotos];
}

- (void)fetchPhotos
{

    NSURL *URL = [FlickrFetcher URLforRecentGeoreferencedPhotos];
    NSData *jsonResult = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:URL];
    NSDictionary * propertyListResults = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonResult
                                                                  options:0
                                                                    error:NULL];


    NSLog(@"Photos = %@" ,propertyListResults);
    self.photos = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should apply for an api key yourself before you can use the assignment.
You can apply using this link:

http://www.flickr.com/services/api/misc.api_keys.html